# Sublime Text 2 - alignment of comma separated values

Tags: alignment, sublimetext2, indentation

I have installed the [Sublime Alignment](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) plugin. It works well for aligning the first character (default is `=`). How can I align this block in Sublime Text 2 in one shot :

> INSERT INTO user VALUES (1, 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Delta');
>   
> INSERT INTO user VALUES (2, 'A', 'B', 'D');

to look like :

> INSERT INTO user VALUES (1, 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Delta');
>   
>  INSERT INTO user VALUES (2, 'A',        'B',      'D');

Even if I add `,` as the alignment character in sublime alignment, it only works for the first occurence of `,`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Align Tab](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab) is quite versatile & can accomplish the alignment and it's not limited to just first character.

[Install](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AlignTab)

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered. Niiiice!